# Redmine 2.1.2 (migrated from 2.0.4) : Migration OK but crashes after login

Tags: debian, redmine

I just migrated from Redmine 2.0.4 to Redmine 2.1.2 (on Debian, with Passenger), following their migration tutorial.
It seemed to work fine.
But when I launch it in my browser, I have redmine's authentification portal and it crashes when I log in with any of my account.
I checked my database and all the account informations are still there.
When I check my redmine log, production, this is what I got :

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml 
OpenIdAuthentication.store is nil. Using in-memory store.
[...]
NoMethodError (undefined method 'session_lifetime?' for #<Class:0x7[...]
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:61 in 'session_expired?'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:50:in 'session_expiration'
```

thank you

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved my issue : During the migration I replaced the settings.yml by my old one, which is a mistake. I replaced it by the original one and it works fine

Comment: I tried this, too. However, it did not solve this particular problem: `undefined method 'session_lifetime?'`